# JGIT - Get every authorized private project

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying to get every project that **a given user** is authorized to "see". For example, when I log into my GitLab account i'm able to choose (from the dashboard) which project I want to explore.

So, what I need is to get that "list" dynamically **with Jgit** in order to show it to the user that's logged in my webapp.

Is it possible to do it using JGit? Or should I use the [GIT-API](https://developer.github.com/v3/?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GIT-API you mention (https://developer.github.com/v3/) is for GitHub, not GitLab.

For GitLab, you should use https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/.

Listing the projects accesible by a user was requested in [gitlab-ce issue 33657](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/33657) and implemented with [gitlab-ce merge_request 12596](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/12596) in [commit 050eae8](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/050eae8c4dff87fef63e79eb60d927d0171b5f7b)

```
GET /users/:user_id/projects
```

You don't need JGit, but a GitLAb API wrapper in Java like [`gmessner/gitlab4j-api`](https://github.com/gmessner/gitlab4j-api).

Comment: Thank you :) But is there a way to do it using Jgit? I'm trying to do it with JGit to keep the consitency of the code.

Comment: @TeslardG I understand, but this has nothing to do with JGit, since it does not involve git commands (JGit is a Java implementation of Git commands). It only involves curl calls, hence my proposition of other Java libraries, which are wrappers around those curl commands.

Comment: Oh, ok :) Thank you!